# How would I test if the mouse cursor location is at (relatively) the same angle from the player as an entity?

Tags: java, trigonometry

This is likely just some simple trigonometry that I've forgotten since I took the class. I want to figure out if the mouse cursor is in the same direction as an entity from the player. Basically, I just want to compare if the angle from the player to the cursor and the angle from the player to an entity are the same, +/- a few degrees for slight autoaim.

Comment: Is this two dimensional geometry? (ie. a top down shooter, rather than a 3d shooter)

Comment: It's top-down, yeah I forgot to mention that sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just spent like an hour trying to work this out using just sine/tan and right angle geometry - it's a more complicated problem than it looks.

It looks like you want to use an `atan2` function.

[See this Math.SE thread.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707673/find-angle-in-degrees-from-one-point-to-another-in-2d-space)

There is a Math.atan2 function for Java. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double,%20double)).

Comment: I know I've been spending days on it and since I haven't had any college level math quite yet I've been struggling... I got it down to using arctangent but I didn't think of atan2. I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: So I've tested using atan2 with the y2-y1, x2-x1 and comparing both, but for some reason the comparison returns true if the cursor is in the same direction as the entity and if it is in the opposite direction of the entity. I'm thinking its because atan2 is occasionally returning NaN.

Comment: Yeah I'm just a complete idiot, my problem was happening because I wasn't subtracting the player x and y from both. Also my error correction number was a little too high, but I've fixed it now.